# I want to disable auto-fill-mode when editing equations

Tags: emacs, auctex

How can I disable auto-fill-mode when editing equations?

I like auto-fill-mode in general, but I'd like to turn it off in specific situations,
e.g. between a `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`
or `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` 
 or `\begin{eqnarray}` and `\end{eqnarray*}` etc.

I did some searching and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008849/suppress-emacs-auto-fill-in-a-selected-region which looked relevant, but I couldn't make it work.
Specifically, I tried changing `%%% BEGIN NO FILL` and `%%% END NO FILL`
to `\begin{eq` and `\end{eq` to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a solution if you are using [AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) (which I highly recommend). Put the following code in your .emacs file:

```lisp
(defvar my-LaTeX-no-autofill-environments
  '("equation" "equation*")
  "A list of LaTeX environment names in which `auto-fill-mode' should be inhibited.")

(defun my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function ()
  "This function checks whether point is currently inside one of
the LaTeX environments listed in
`my-LaTeX-no-autofill-environments'. If so, it inhibits automatic
filling of the current paragraph."
  (let ((do-auto-fill t)
        (current-environment "")
        (level 0))
    (while (and do-auto-fill (not (string= current-environment "document")))
      (setq level (1+ level)
            current-environment (LaTeX-current-environment level)
            do-auto-fill (not (member current-environment my-LaTeX-no-autofill-environments))))
    (when do-auto-fill
      (do-auto-fill))))

(defun my-LaTeX-setup-auto-fill ()
  "This function turns on auto-fill-mode and sets the function
used to fill a paragraph to `my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function'."
  (auto-fill-mode)
  (setq auto-fill-function 'my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-LaTeX-setup-auto-fill)
```

Let's go from the bottom to the top to understand what this does. The "add-hook" function registers a call-back that is invoked every time you open a .tex file. The hook variable `LaTeX-mode-hook` is provided by AUCTeX.

The call-back is the function `my-LaTeX-setup-auto-fill` which we define above. It turns on `auto-fill-mode` and then tells it to use the function `my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function` to actually perform the automatic filling.

In order for this construction to work, it is important that you don't turn auto-fill mode off an on again afterwards, or else the `my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function` won't be used. If you already have a mechanism in place that automatically turns on `auto-fill-mode` when you edit a .tex file, you should probably turn that off and have the above function turn it on for you instead.

The definition of `my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function` can be found above. What it basically does is this: it checks whether you're currently inside an "equation" environment and if so, it does nothing. If you're not inside an "equation" environment, it does auto-fill.

Finally, the variable at the top defines for which LaTeX environments auto-fill should be inhibited. I currently put "equation" and "equation*" there, but you can add further environments if you like.

Comment: There's a small typo in the documentation string of `my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function`: the environments are listed in `my-LaTeX-no-autofill-environments`, not `my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function`.

Comment: Fixed, thanks (damn auto-completion...)